# How should you represent a short Unordered list

Tags: icons, lists, input-fields

I have a list of exactly 2 steps a user can follow either the first or the second can be completed first, both have to be completed for the next action to occur.

I have large circular icons which glow green or red depending on whether the action under the specific item is properly completed. Beside each icon is the field name (what to do here).

My question is what is the best iconography to represent these separate items. I originally had just a grey circle that glowed green or red, but I feel it is very bland and doesn't get the point across that this is a field (remember this is not a form UI i'm working on).

I was thinking of putting some distinct icon inside the grey circles, maybe a simple shape (i.e. Circle, Square etc.)? Or since the way the items are placed seems like the list is ordered, so using letters which are pretty distinct (i.e. "A" and "B") then allow users to complete it in which ever order they like?

Comment: Probably a screenshot would help us understand the situation more.

Comment: We're missing a lot of context here. What are these 'steps'? Are they complex tasks? Is there an even split between which step people prefer to tackle first, or is one more obvious than the other in terms of being completed first?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using a Red X and a Green Checkmark? Simple, Easy to tell apart, common affordance...

Comment: What about the idle state? is everything Red X at the start?

Comment: By definition, you haven't completed the task when you start working on it, yes?

Comment: ya, everything is incomplete when you start, when you focus then unfocus it checks if completed correctly or not

Comment: So how about pale yellow circle when untouched, green tick inside it when filled correctly, and red cross when not?